# PHP: Displaying table contents on html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

New to PHP. Trying to simply output the contents of a mySQL table onto my HTML page. Here is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div>
            <?php
                $hostname = "XXXXX";
                $username = "XXXXX";
                $password = "XXXXX";
                $db_name = "XXXXX";

                //connect to database
                mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect to server");
                mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select database");

                $sql="SELECT * FROM myTable";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                if (!$result) {die("SQL error retrieving data.");}

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo $row['field1'] . $row['field2'] . "</br>";
                }    

                mysql_close();
            ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

My output is simply this:

> "; } mysql_close(); ?>

I know that there is data in the table. I can't see what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: If you see php code in the page, your page is not getting executed as php. Either its not installed, or not using a supported extension.

Comment: Probably not the issue but you should be using <br> or <br />, not </br>

Comment: @datasage probably not the issue since you're only seeing a part of code not all of it. My guess is the `</br>` (should be `<br />`) is escaping the text, since that's where the output begins.

Comment: Try replacing all your PHP code with just an echo statement to ensure your server is parsing the PHP properly. By the way, it's `<br />` not `</br>`

Comment: @PRPGFerret, forward slash doesn't escape, you're thinking of backslash.

Comment: It sounds like a string in the echo statement isn't being terminated properly, causing the code after it to be echo'd instead of executed. Are you sure the code sample you posted matches the one you're actually using?

Comment: Nono I mean could broken html tag escape a php statement?

Comment: Since you're new to PHP it's a good time to start learning MySQLi or PDO. mysql_* is no longer supported. You're probably following an old tutorial.

Comment: The code isn't executing at all, if you view the source, you would see all the php code. The browser is interpreting the start of the php tag to the end of the br as one big tag and not displaying it.

Comment: Change your file extension to `.php`

Comment: @datasage you are absolutely right

Comment: @Herbert That was it. Thanks! Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Go ahead and accept echo_Me's if you like cause that's what I would have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change your file extension to `.php` instead of `.html`

- Please change your connection to `PDO` or `mysqli` because `mysql` is soon deprecated

Comment: To my understanding, mysql _is_ deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not interpreted as PHP code. Thus, the Browser interprets `<?php` as the start of a HTML element that is closed by `/br>`. This HTML element is unknown to the browser and therefore ignored. The following lines

```
";
            }    

            mysql_close();
        ?>
```

are then visible in the browser, because they are not part of a HTML element.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to uncomment an appropriate extension for `mysql` from `php.ini`, if you have php installed of course.

Also I would suggest you to use `sqlite`. It is easy to start and manage you DB, check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php